# Is there a way to merge multiple SWF files and an XML file into one SWF?

Tags: xml, flash

I am working with a client that has provided me with multiple SWF files and an XML file. These files together create a brochure type flash application. In this application, there is a base layout in the form of a SWF file, a table of contents that gets populated by looking at the provided XML file, and other SWF files that function as the pages of the application. Flash isn't part of my normal work activities, so I apologize for coming at this with little background.

They want me to add the files to their site through their content management system, however, that system doesn't take in XML files. I've had various ideas on how to solve this, but haven't found a proper solution.

The first idea I have is to find a way to merge all these files into a single SWF file, which leads to the title of the question. Is there a tool that will allow me to do this without having to use flash myself (the client hasn't provided me with the flash suite)? I've explored SWF Tools but it didn't seem to handle XML files.

The second idea I have is to modify the type of file data file the SWF is working with from XML to a format the CMS would allow, however, I imagine this would need me to go into the file and update this.

If either of these ways are possible, or there is a better solution, I would love to hear it.

Thanks.

Comment: This depends very much on the CMS. Can you not host the swf files and the xml on the same server via ftp, but only reference the files when embedding to an html page from the cms ? I'm guessing one of the reasons why the xml is external is to make it easy to update without recompiling the swf, but this would no longer be the case if you merge the swf files + the xml, correct ?

Comment: It's kind of a POC for me to get it to work this way, so I was trying to see if those options were possible since my knowledge of flash is limited. And , yes, merging the swf / xml files would make them lose that ability to update without, but that's fine. They just want to content up there.

Comment: do you have the source code for your swf files ?